# OnEntry won't work with my data validation

Tags: vba, validation

I have a data validation that consists of yes and no in the first column of my sheet. I have a sub that auto opens other subs (to color the entire row based on the yes or the no) with an `OnEntry` function. However, because I'm using the data validation, auto open sub won't start because I didn't enter anything.

If I type in Yes or No it works fine, but not if I use the data validation.

What do I need to do with my auto open sub to make it recognize that when I select an option within data validation, it starts?

Thanks

Comment: Could you edit your question to include your code please.

Comment: Add a call to `OnEntry` in Workbook's code `Sub Workbook_Open()` should do.